# Webview is blank without any error in Android 6.0, working fine in lower version.

Tags: android, webview

1.In Android 6.0 it is not working.  Whenever i open the webview, it is blank without any error.  Webview is working fine in lower version. 
 2. Inside LinearLayout i added the webview. 
 3. Here i will share my part of the code.
 4.Normally with static lat , long it loading. Whenever i try to get current location , problem occurs.

In assets:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
```

---

In onCreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                // Marshmallow+ Permission APIs
                fuckMarshMallow();
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
                    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJS(this), "Android");
            webview.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
            webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
            webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

           webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webview.setInitialScale(1);
            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new Materialformfilling.GeoWebViewClient());
            // Below required for geolocation
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new Materialformfilling.GeoWebChromeClient());

            webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                    // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                    Materialformfilling.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                }
            });
           webview.loadUrl(url);




      public class GeoWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                           final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
                // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        }

        /**
         * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
         */
        public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(Materialformfilling.this);

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;

                if (loadingDialog == null || !loadingDialog.isShowing())
                    loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Materialformfilling.this, "",
                            "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    // do something

                                }
                            });

                loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
            }


            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                        WebResourceError error) {


                if (isConnected()) {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "onReceivedError : " + error.getDescription(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                } else {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                            snackBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                }

                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view,
                                            WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

                if (isConnected()) {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "HttpError : " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase() + +errorResponse.getStatusCode(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                    snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                } else {
                    final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
                            snackBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    snackBar.show();
                }
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {

                    if (null != loadingDialog) {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        loadingDialog = null;
                        Constant.print("check 1111111111111111");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Check if there is any connectivity
         *
         * @return is Device Connected
         */
        public boolean isConnected() {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (null != cm) {
                NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return (info != null && info.isConnected());
            }

            return false;

        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private void fuckMarshMallow() {
            List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

            final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Show Location");
            if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
                if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {

                    // Need Rationale
                    String message = "App need access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);

                    for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                        message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

                    showMessageOKCancel(message,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(Materialformfilling.this, "No new Permission Required- Launching App .You are Awesome!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Materialformfilling.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsList.add(permission);
                // Check for Rationale Option
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

---

Please help me

Comment: did you add INTERNET permission in manifest file

Comment: yes, added. Working fine till 5.0